# Why does the C++ standard's index have this entry for "undefined behavior"?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Both C++11 and C++14, in their index, have their entry for *"undefined behavior"* pointing to the section `[istreambuf.iterator]`. As far as I can see, there is no obvious reason for this, and C++03's entry pointed to `[defns.undefined]`.

What am I missing? Or is it just an editorial mistake?

(As of 13th October, I cannot find any matching [open](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html) or [closed](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_closed.html) Core Working Group issues matching this observation.)

Comment: It seems to persist even in the latest N4140 draft of C++14, it's probably a missed-ref latex issue.

Comment: Can someone explain the downvotes? That is a reasonable question.

Comment: it's undefined behavior, anything can happen!

Comment: @Columbo I stopped asking these questions... some idiots are just downvoting without thinking or reading carefully.

Comment: @vsoftco: Thanks for looking that up for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an editorial error.

Essentially the [line here](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/blob/b1bb60b4bf574411074c022bd89fffd113fec551/source/iterators.tex#L3027) should say `\indextext{undefined}` instead.

The C++ standard uses `\makeindex` and a bunch of macros to generate their index and there is only one instance of `\indextext{undefined behavior}` being used and it points to `istreambuf.iterator` instead of pointing where it should. They tend to use `\indextext{undefined}` to accumulate all the different undefined behaviour cases but it seems someone used `\indextext{undefined behavior}` instead.

Answer (score 9):

The people over at [*std-discussion* seem to agree that this is just an editorial issue](https://groups.google.com/a/isocpp.org/forum/embed/?place=forum/std-discussion&showsearch=true&showpopout=true&parenturl=https://isocpp.org/forums/iso-c-standard-discussion#!topic/std-discussion/ju1LrAJvqOo).

I therefore raised it as such, so that it became [draft issue 409](https://github.com/cplusplus/draft/issues/409) on github; it was promptly resolved and closed.

I will one day update this answer a final time with an identifier for the first draft containing the fix; the first standard it appears in will be C++17.

Comment: In case you didn't know, for editorial issues in the standard you can fix them yourself and issue a pull request. If you are inclined to do that sort of thing, that is.

Comment: @TimSeguine: I'm not a git user so I opt to get someone else to do it ;()